# Adding selected items from Datagridview to a list collection

Tags: c#, collections, datagridview

I'm having a trouble adding selected elements from a DGV to a model class type list , the constructor contains 10 parameters according to the image describing the DGV  , the C# code is the following :

```
List<Client> Listclient = new List<Client>();

    for (int i = ClientsGrid.RowCount; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if ((bool)ClientsGrid.Rows[i-1].Cells[0].Value == true)
                    {
                        Listclient.Add(new Client(ClientsGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), ClientsGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()
                            , ClientsGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), ClientsGrid.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
                            ClientsGrid.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), ClientsGrid.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString(),
                            ClientsGrid.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString(), ClientsGrid.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString(),
                            ClientsGrid.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString()));
                    }
                }
```

[Here is an image of how the DGV looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwUAp.jpg)

I'm expecting that the list gets added the rows selected from the DGV and to confirm that , i added a button that prints the last name of each client on the list .
as shown :

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           for(int i = 0; i < Listclient.Count ; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Listclient[i].LastName.ToString());

            }


        }
```

Comment: What is the actual question? Expected vs actual output?

Comment: the actual output is that i'm not managing to get the rows added to the list even though the code seems logical , the expected output is that when i add the elements to the list and test that by MessageBox printing one of the properties of each of the list's items

Comment: Do you actually enter inside the if statement? Does it hit the code starting with `Listclient.Add...`? Also, it'd be great if you could add  the expected and output to the question to allow others to help you easier :)

Comment: Actually the if statement throws a nullReferenceException and i don't know why exactly because the for loop is decrementing starting from the RowsCount number , also sorry the index is [i] not [i-1] ....

Comment: Can you add the information of the exception to the question? One of your values must be null.

Comment: You should be aware that IF the `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` is NEVER set then it will be `null`. The `null` value in the check box cell would indicate that the check box has NOT been set and is therefore NOT checked. You should check to see if the cell's `Value`  is `null` before trying to get its `Value`. Something like…  `if (ClientsGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null && (bool)ClientsGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == true)…`

Comment: The same idea is going to apply to EACH cell `Value`… you need to check and make sure the cells `Value` is not `null` BEFORE you call its `ToString()` method. Something like… `if (ClientsGrid.Rows[i].Cells[X].Value != null) {…  //OK to call the cells Value.ToString()`.